# Laplace transform of a signal

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I've to find the Laplace transform of a voltage signal:

$$\text{U}\left(t\right)=\left|\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\right|=\left|\hat{\text{u}}\right|\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)}$$

Where all the variables are real numbers.

So, we get:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\cdot\left|\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\right|\space\text{d}t=\left|\hat{\text{u}}\right|\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\cdot\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)}\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\frac{\left|\hat{\text{u}}\right|}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\cdot\sqrt{1-\cos\left(2\omega t+2\varphi\right)}\space\text{d}t$$

Comment: Shouldn't the absolute values return a scalar?

Comment: A general technique is to get rid of absolute values. For that, separate the integral into a sum of integrals on intervals $[a_k,b_k]$ where the quantity inside the absolute values bars has a homogeneous sign (plus or minus), with $a_k=\frac{1}{\omega}((2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi)$ and  $b_k=\frac{1}{\omega}((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi)$, in general.

Comment: In any event, $\vert \hat {\boldsymbol u} \vert = 1$.